# Contents from FrameLayout appears on above Navigation Drawer:Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-framelayout

I am new into Android and I'm implementing a Navigation Drawer, So far I have managed to list my items in the Drawer and added a fragment into my framelayout.
The homepage works normally , but when I open the Drawer, the buttons from my FrameLayout appears on above of the Navigation Drawer.

I need to make the framelayout appear below the Navigation Drawer.

My Code as follows

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.shimplyapp.MainActivity" >


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.shimplyapp.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >


    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_navigation_drawer.xml**

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"    
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:context="com.example.shimplyapp.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

**home_default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etxt_sn_enter_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:hint="enter_search_ item here.."
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="15"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_lm_search_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="search"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_lm_view_stores"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="store"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_lm_view_deals"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="deal"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />            
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my calling fragment from **MainActivity**

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    //flag a global variable initially flag = 0;    

    if(flag ==0){
        fragment = new HomePage();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
        flag = 1;
    }
        //..... rest is switch cases for calling different fragments 
}
```

Comment: place the frame layout above the navigation drawer in xml

Answer (score 1):

Your **activity_main.xml** should be like this .Change it and test

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context="com.example.shimplyapp.MainActivity" >    

        <Fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:name="com.example.shimplyapp.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You actually don't need the relative layout around it but yes this is correct.  The reason for it being, a drawer layout needs to have exactly 2 children, the main screen, and then the drawer layout. Each of those layouts can have children if need.

Comment: Well thanx for suggestion of not keeping relative layout, just ignore it, btw when I modified my code into this new 'activity_main.xml` what happened is , when i swipe to right , the drawer gets open, but its not getting closed when i swipe it to left. I have to click on above menu bar to close it.

Comment: Can you show me some details that what and how you are adding drawer to your activity.